# Using the wizard view, is it possible to hide the Submit button on all but the final section?

Tags: orbeon

I have created a form with 6 sections and configured Cancel, Next, Prev and Submit buttons in `properties-local.xml`.

It is usually not advisable to allow the end-user to submit the form until they have at least reached the final section. The only way I can see that this may be possible is to use buttons within the form and by checking which section is currently in focus.

I notice that this has been fixed for Orbeon 2016.1 (see [Is it possible in orben to hide or disable the "send" button until a form is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35058268/is-it-possible-in-orben-to-hide-or-disable-the-send-button-until-a-form-is-fin)), but just wondered whether there is a workaround for Orbeon v4.10?

Comment: I have downloaded Orbeon 2016.1 and the submit button still seems to show on all pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2016.1, this requires the following conditions:

1. Use of the `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.inner` property.
2. Use the wizard's validated mode.

The documentation on this was missing. I have just [added it](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/feature/wizard-view.html#buttons-visibility). I hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, many thanks Erik - that's great!  Glad I could help getting the documentation updated.  Jake.

Comment: No problem, and we also appreciate that!